# How do I make jQuery Datepicker press the submit button automatically after a date has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

So as soon as a date is selected on the Datepicker I want a button to be pressed that will submit the date. This way users won't need to click on a button to submit dates they want to look at.

My jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $('#date').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
    });  
</script>
```

And then the HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit </button>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check this event  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onSelect event like this   ,[Working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/qdnr0y9t/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $("#yourFormId").submit();
            //OR $("#yourButton").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please tell me if you see anything wrong because for some reason it doesn't work:`<script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#date" ).datepicker({
   numberOfMonths: 3,
   showButtonPanel: true
  });
  $('#date').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
  });  

  $(function() {
  $('#date').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            //$("#calendarForm").submit();
            $("#submit").click();
        }
  });
  });
   </script> `

Comment: @Karma you initialize `datepicker( { ... } )` two times try this `$(function() { $( "#date" ).datepicker( { numberOfMonths: 3, showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", onSelect: function( date ) { $("#submit").click(); } } ); } );`

Comment: @ostapische Please see this [link](https://paste.ee/p/EX4iN) with the pasted code. for some reason the calendar gets stuck, if I click it and I click out somewhere else it will not close the calendar. And also it will not submit the date.

Comment: @Karma i have edited your code in the link you gave and creataed a working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/7uy4edjz/

Comment: @sajanyamaha I have literally copied your code and now my calendar doesn't show up. This is how it [looks](https://paste.ee/p/jG5e2)

Comment: @Karma the code is correct ,you just need to keep the form elements before scripts,i have done this for you here,https://paste.ee/p/KHAIS now it will work

Answer (score 1):

I guess your datepicker is in the form .. Then do this :)

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).parents("form").submit();
        }
    });
    $('#date').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');

});
```

You can also minify your code by adding the dateFormat option directly to the init of datepicker

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).parents("form").submit();
        },
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm' 
    });       
});
```